# Excel Formula Drop Down List Dependency

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula to select certain responses from a drop down depending on what was previously selected.

```
=IF($C13="Monday",OFFSET(INDEX(K6:K7,MATCH($C15,J6:J7)),
0,0,1,MATCH("zzz",INDEX(K6:L7,MATCH($C15,J6:J7,0),0))),

IF($C13="Tuesday",OFFSET(INDEX(K11:K12,MATCH($C15,J11:J12,0)),
0,0,1,MATCH("zzz", INDEX(K11:L12,MATCH($C15,J11:J12,0),0))),

IF($C13="Wednesday", OFFSET(INDEX(K16:K17,MATCH($C15,J16:J17,0)),
0,0,1,MATCH("zzz", INDEX(K16:L17,MATCH($C15,J16:J17,0),0))))))
```

The problem here is that when I paste it into the data validation drop down list box it does not fit. I even gave some coordinates defined names, to put in this formula and it still would not fit.

The structure of my data and questions are followed:

[image: Excel Data structure]

So it will first ask `day of week`, then `time`, and depending on which `day of week` and `time` is selected the corresponding `fruit` will be seen in the drop down.

Is there another way to shorten this formula, or another work around, to get the desired results?

Comment: can you supply a screenshot of B78:D79? It is not clear what data sits in that range and how it relates to the Fruit list.

Comment: Also, please read this [message for cross-posters](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184) and stick to one site at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if your large formula won't fit in data validation, you could place the large formula in some other cell, and simply set the data validation equal to that cell. You could then hide the row or column that contains your large formula so the user does not see it.

E.g. If you're not using the "H" column, paste your large formula into cell H1, set the data validation to `=H1`, then hide the "H" column.

Comment: That does work but when there is more than 1 drop down selection I get a #VALUE error.

Comment: Could you post screenshots of both sheets?